# How to access fields returned by Polymorphic query in apex/soql?

Tags: apex, soql, fields

This might seem to be a fairly simple question, but I am unable to figure out how to use the fields returned by a Polymorphic SOQL query.

For example: I ran the following query in dev console's query editor:

```
SELECT TYPEOF WHAT
WHEN OPPORTUNITY THEN Name,StageName
WHEN ACCOUNT THEN Name
ELSE Email
END
FROM EVENT
```

It shows that I have one record which matches this criteria, but it doesn't show the record details.
Here is the output:
[image]

When I run this segment of code in Anonymous window, the list only prints WhatId and the Id of the event itself.

```
list<Event> newlist=[SELECT TYPEOF WHAT
WHEN OPPORTUNITY THEN StageName
ELSE Email
END
FROM EVENT];

system.debug(newlist);

if(newlist.get(0).What instanceof Opportunity){
    //what should I do here to access fields of opportunity?
}
```

I understand that I can fetch the WhatId from the list and use that to query the fields on Opportunity object. But if I need to run the DML again to get the required fields, what is the use of the polymorphic DML statement?

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of how to retrieve field values returned from Polymorphic query.

```
list<Event> newlist=[SELECT TYPEOF WHAT
                    WHEN OPPORTUNITY THEN StageName
                    ELSE Email
                    END
                    FROM EVENT];
```

To access the StageName value of the Opportunity, first create an instance of `Opportunity` object based on `evt.What` as below and then you will get the `StageName`.

```
for(Event evt:newlist){
    if(evt.What instanceof Opportunity){
        //what should I do here to access fields of opportunity?
        System.debug('evt.WhatId=' + evt.WhatId);
        Opportunity opty = evt.What;
        System.debug('opty=' + opty);
        System.debug('opty.StageName=' + opty.StageName);
    }
}
```

[image: Debug log]

But if you try to access StageName like this way `evt.What.StageName` without typecasting to Opportunity then compiler will complain as `StageName` is not an attribute of that Polymorphic object.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works :)